# Pass char pointer/array to a function

Tags: c++, c, pointers, char, char-pointer

I am trying to understand char pointer in C more but one thing gets me.

Supposed I would like to pass a char pointer into a function and change the value that pointer represents. A example as followed:

```
int Foo (char *(&Msg1), char* Msg2, char* Msg3){
    char *MsgT = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*60);
    strcpy(MsgT,"Foo - TEST");
    Msg1 = MsgT; // Copy address to pointer
    strcpy(Msg2,MsgT); // Copy string to char array
    strcpy(Msg3,MsgT); // Copy string to char pointer
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    char* Msg1; // Initial char pointer
    char Msg2[10]; // Initial char array
    char* Msg3 = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 10); // Preallocate pointer memory
    Foo(Msg1, Msg2, Msg3);
    printf("Msg1: %s\n",Msg1); // Method 1
    printf("Msg2: %s\n",Msg2); // Method 2
    printf("Msg3: %s\n",Msg3); // Method 3
    free(Msg1);    
    free(Msg3);
    return 0;
}
```

In the above example, I listed all working methods I know for passing char pointer to function. The one I don't understand is **Method 1**.

What is the meaning of **`char *(&Msg1)`** for the first argument that is passed to the function **`Foo`**?

Also, it seems like **method 2** and **method3** are widely introduced by books and tutorials, and some of them even referring those methods as *the most correct ways to pass arrays/pointers*. I wonder that **Method 1** looks very nice to me, especially when I write my API, users can easily pass a null pointer into function without preallocate memory. The only downside may be potential memory leak if users forget to free the memory block (same as **method 3**). Is there any reason we should prefer using **Method 2 or 3** instead **Method 3**?

Comment: Did you see this example somewhere? Instead of `char *(&Msg1)`, `char **Msg1` is commonly used.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's a note I took for long long time ago. I don't even remember where I got this. I understand how `**Msg1` work, but they are different, right?

Comment: Yes because `char *(&Msg1)` wouldn't compile. If you know how `char **Msg1` works then I guess you know answer to your question.

Comment: `char *(&Msg1)` is C++ pass-by-reference.

Comment: Learning both C and C++ at the same is not a good idea! *They are sufficiently similar that you may think places where they are very different don't matter much.*

Comment: I compiled and run it successfully. That's why I don't understand.

Comment: @StevenChang it wouldn't compile with a c compiler, but compiles fine with C++ compiler, in C it's considered as syntax error, while in C++, it's considered as [reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C%2B%2B%29), if you don't know about references, you should read more about them

Comment: I see. My project does combine C and C++. I know it might not be a good idea mixing them but some third party libraries use C and some use C++. Now I feel better for my question and know where to study for. Thanks guys.

Comment: So someone may help me clarify ..Is this true...In **C**, there is absolutely no way I can simply pass a char pointer (such as `*p` not address of pointer `&p`) (not array, i.e. `p[10]`) to a function that modifies the value of that pointer, without pre-allocating it?

Comment: @StevenChang: Correct.  In __C__, there is absolutely no way  to pass _anything_ to a function that modifies the value, except by passing a pointer to it.  That includes pointers.  If you want to change the value of a pointer, you need to pass a pointer to the pointer that needs changing.

Comment: "In C, there is absolutely no way ... without pre-allocating it?" -- No, you just pass the address of the pointer, which does the same thing under the hood as passing a reference.

Comment: @bytefire "because char *(&Msg1) wouldn't compile" -- The question includes a C++ tag. If you're unfamiliar with that language, best avoid making absolute claims about what will or won't compile.

Comment: @StevenChang it is possible to have a program using some C files and some C++ files, however you need to know what you are doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`int f(char* p)` is the usual way in C to pass the pointer `p` to the function `f` when `p` already points to the memory location that you need (usually because there is a character array already allocated there as in your Method 2 or Method 3).

`int f(char** p)` is the usual way in C to pass the pointer `p` to the function `f` when you want `f` to be able to modify the pointer `p` for the caller of this function. Your Method 1 is an example of this; you want `f` to allocate new memory and use `p` to tell the caller where that memory is.

`int f(char*& p)` is C++, not C. Since this compiles for you, we know you are using a C++ compiler.

Comment: Now I got it it's different syntax for different compilers. But if using `f(char** p)`, you need to pass `&Msg` after initialing the pointer, right? It doesn't look like it's same as **`Method 1`**. If coding in C++, which way is preferred and why?

Comment: You are correct that you would need to pass `&Msg` to `f(char** p)`, because `Msg` is of type `char*`. In C++ I would prefer `f(char*& p)`, partly because you can just pass `Msg`, but also because `&` is a way to clearly indicate that you want pass-by-reference semantics, whereas a `char**` might just be an array of strings in another context.

Comment: Thank you.I think your explanation is brief and clear. This is exact I need.

Comment: @StevenChang " for different compilers" -- No, for different *languages*. " If coding in C++, which way is preferred and why?" -- References are preferred. For why, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781661/c-why-do-you-need-references-when-you-have-pointers

Answer (score 0):

Consider what happens when you take an argument of type `int&` (reference to int) :

```
void f(int &x) {
    x++;
}

void g(int x) {
    x++;
}

int main() {
    int i = 5;
    f(i);
    assert(i == 6);
    g(i);
    assert(i == 6);
}
```

The same behaviour can be achieved by taking a pointer-to-int (`int *x`), and modifying it through (*x)++. The only difference in doing this is that the caller has to call f(&i), and that the caller can pass an invalid pointer to f. Thus, references are generally safer and should be preferred whenever possible.

Taking an argument of type `char*` (pointer-to-char) means that both the caller and the function see the same block of memory "through" that pointer. If the function modifies the memory pointed to by the `char*`, it will persist to the caller:

```
void f(char* p) {
    (*p) = 'p';
    p = NULL; //no efect outside the function
}

int main() {
    char *s = new char[4];
    strcpy(s, "die");
    char *address = s; //the address which s points to
    f(s);
    assert(strcmp(s, "pie") == 0);
    assert(s == address); //the 'value' of the variable s, meaning the actual addres that is pointed to by it, has not changed
}
```

Taking an argument of type `char*&` ( reference-to-(pointer-to-char) ) is much the same as taking int&:
If the function modifies the memory pointed to by the pointer, the caller will see it as usual. However, if the function modifies the **value** of the pointer (its address), the caller will also see it.

```
void f(char* &p) {
    (*p) = 'p';
    p = NULL;
}

int main() {
    char *s = new char[4];
    strcpy(s, "die");
    char *address = s; //the address which s points to
    f(s);
    assert(strcmp(address, "pie") == 0); //the block that s initially pointed to was modified
    assert(s == NULL); //the 'value' of the variable s, meaning the actual addres that is pointed to by it, was changed to NULL by the function
}
```

Again, you could take a `char**` (pointer-to-pointer-to-char), and modify f to use `**p = 'p'; *p = NULL`, and the caller would have to call f(&s), with the same implications.

Note that you cannot pass arrays by reference, i.e. if s was defined as `char s[4]`, the call f(s) in the second example would generate a compiler error.

Also note that this only works in C++, because C has no references, only pointers.

You would usually take `char**` or `char*&` when your function needs to return a pointer to a memory block it allocated. You see `char**` more often, because this practice is less common in C++ than in C, where references do not exist.

As for whether to use references or pointers, it is a highly-debated topic, as you will notice if you search google for "c++ pointer vs reference arguments".