# Copy constructor or assignment operator? What am I missing?

Tags: c++, this, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

I'm trying to implement a copy constructor and an overloaded assignment constructor.
I've an Employee class that has three data members.   1-name    2-title   3-salary.

```
Employee::Employee(const Employee &emp)
{
    name = emp.name;
    title = emp.title;
    salary = emp.salary;
    cout << "\nOverloaded copy constructor called\n";
}
Employee Employee::operator = (const Employee &emp) //Overloading the assignment operator.
{
    name = emp.name;
    title = emp.title;
    salary = emp.salary;
    cout << "\nOverloaded assignment operator called\n";
    return emp;         //Or return *this.
}
```

Here's what I do not understand:
1- I haven't got to the "this" pointer. Should my overloaded assignment operator return *this or the emp object. Because it seems to me that that object in the parameter is the right hand object at the assignment. So shouldn't I return the left hand object with *this(if that's what *this will be doing)?
2- At the main function, I tried to call to call the assignment operator first and the copy constructor after that. So I was expecting that I will see the cout statements I've included there one after the other however, Here's my output:

Overloaded copy constructor called
Overloaded assignment operator called
Overloaded copy constructor called
Overloaded copy constructor called

Why is this happening?

3-Do I have to pass the objects with const? The book I'm learning from does not.

In the main I just wrote

```
Employee x;
x = another;
Employee y = x;
```

"another" is just a (poorly named) Employee object I've initialized earlier in my code.
So shouldn't the first assignment output
"Overloaded assignment operator called" and the second assignment (Which isn't an assignment but a copy according to my understanding) output                                        "Overloaded copy constructor called"

Comment: For number 2 and 3 - Show us the code associated with that.

Answer (score 3):

An assignment operator is normally implemented as

```
Employee& Employee::operator = (const Employee &emp)
{
    name = emp.name;
    title = emp.title;
    salary = emp.salary;
    cout << "\nOverloaded assignment operator called\n";
    return *this;      
}
```

note the difference in return type as a reference. You may find this question/answer to be useful [Why must the copy assignment operator return a reference/const reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105798/why-must-the-copy-assignment-operator-return-a-reference-const-reference) . Without seeing your code that you refer to in your `main()` function we would only be guessing as to what is happening in your code.

Answer (score 0):

> 1- I haven't got to the "this" pointer. Should my overloaded
>   assignment operator return *this or the emp object. Because it seems
>   to me that that object in the parameter is the right hand object at
>   the assignment. So shouldn't I return the left hand object with
>   *this(if that's what *this will be doing)?

You should return `*this`.

Note also that first you should check against self-assignment and return a reference:

```
Employee& Employee::operator = (const Employee &emp) //Overloading the assignment operator.
{
    if ( this != &emp)
    {
        name = emp.name;
        title = emp.title;
        salary = emp.salary;
    }
    cout << "\nOverloaded assignment operator called\n";
    return *this;
}
```

[Here you can find how to write assignment operator.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_operator_%28C%2B%2B%29)

> 2- At the main function, I tried to call to call the assignment
>   operator first and the copy constructor after that. So I was expecting
>   that I will see the cout statements I've included there one after the
>   other however

Please insert this code from `main()` so we can tell you more.

Comment: I've seen this if statement in other questions here but I did not understand the need for it. What do you mean by self-assignment?

Comment: Employee e; e=e; Here this is explicit so looks unlikely however you can do something like this by mistake when you process objects in algorithms and structures.

Comment: I've changed my assignment operator. But I've got an error when in the if statement (something about != does not match the operands) so I changed the if statement to                             if(this != &emp)                                                    and I returned *this. But my output now is                  Overloaded copy constructor called
Overloaded assignment operator called
Overloaded copy constructor called

Comment: In the main I just wrote      


    Employee x;
    x = another;
    Employee y = x;

"another" is just a (poorly named) Employee object I've initialized earlier in my code.      
So shouldn't the first assignment output                                               
"Overloaded assignment operator called" and the second assignment (Which isn't an assignment but a copy according to my understanding) output                                        "Overloaded copy constructor called"

Comment: how did you create and initialize and pass to this place "another" object? first copy constructor is called probably for this object

Comment: Oh dammit you are right. I've initialized my "another" object by copying it from a derived Engineer class. At the time of course I have not implemented my copy constructor. Good guess piotrus :). What about the const? All the question on stackoverflow have used the const in both but the book I'm using does not for either.

Comment: very well, I'm glad that it helped

Answer (score 0):

Edited : Let's copy constructor to do everything for you

```
Employee::Employee(const Employee &emp)
{
   if(this != &emp)
   {
       name = emp.name;
       title = emp.title;
       salary = emp.salary;
   }

  cout << "\nOverloaded copy constructor called\n";
}
Employee Employee::operator = (const Employee &emp) //Overloading the assignment   .
{       
   return emp;    //Having common assignment operations similar to copy constructor
}
```

Comment: You are returning a reference to a local variable, which is bad as `temp` will be destructed and invalidate the reference. Your code also don't modify `this` nor return `*this` ( which is the default behavior of `operator=` )

Answer (score 0):

1. overloaded assignment operator should return *this pointer. You may implement a private method which would copy the class members and just call it from copy constructor/assignment operator, which would result in less duplicated code.

   ```
   void Employee::copy(const A& rhs) throw() 
   {
     name = rhs.name;
     title = rhs.title;
     salary = rhs.salary;
   }

   Employee::Employee(const Employee& rhs)
   {
     copy(rhs);
     //  cout << "copy constructor" << endl;
   }

   Employee& operator=(const Employee& rhs)
   {
     copy(rhs);
     //  cout << "assignment operator" << endl;
     return *this;
   }
   ```
2. Your implementation of assignment operator does return the Employee object by value (it should be by reference), so as the effect the temporary objects are created by calling the copy c-tor.

   ```
   Overloaded copy constructor called // don't know where this printout comes from as I don't know what happens with 'another' object
   Overloaded assignment operator called // x = another; call
   Overloaded copy constructor called // the temporary object created by assignment operator's return statement (*this should be returned by reference not by value)
   Overloaded copy constructor called // Employee y = x; cal
   ```
3. You should always pass the input parameters as const when you don't intend to modify them. I presume you ask about passing Employee objects as const references in assignment operator etc? - they should be const references

A bit more about exception safety and self assignment handling in assignment operator:
[GotW 59](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/059.htm) and [GotW 23](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/023.htm)