# c++ passing pointers to method

Tags: c++, pointers

I have the following functions:

```
Triangle* operator=(Triangle& other) const
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < other.getNumOfPoints(); i++)
    {
        this->addPoint(other.getPoint(i));
    }

    color = other.color;

    //type stays the same
    return this;
}


Point* Polygon::getPoint(int index) const
{
    return _points.at(index);
}

void Polygon::addPoint(Point* p) {
    Point* newp = new Point; //create a copy of the original pt
    newp->setX(p->getX());
    newp->setY(p->getY());
    _points.push_back(newp);
}
```

I am sure each understand what the objects mean, they are pretty straight forward.
First method is located inside Triangle class which inherit from Polygon.

Problem is in the first method when I use

```
this->addPoint(other.getPoint(i));
```

Eclipse states its Invalid argument.
Can I get an explanation of why is it error when getPoint returns Point pointer and AddPoint function requires a Point pointer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: An assignment operator in C++ is usually written to return a reference to the current object, not a pointer.  Why the weird implementation?

Comment: And it is usually not `const`, because it is supposed to modify the object being assigned to.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie can you explain to me why does it matter? because when i assign, either way the object that receives the data is the This..so why should i return Triangle ? what do you suggest to change?

Comment: @OriRefael so that this is valid: `t1 = t2 = t3` (there `tn` are variables of type `Triangle`

Comment: @bolov why isn't that valid when working with pointers?

Comment: You are not returning a reference when you return a pointer.  You are returning a pointer.  Second, it is counter-intuitive to have `=` return anything but a reference to the current object.  Third, an assignment operator should be similar in design to your copy constructor.  Did you implement your copy ctor to return a pointer (which you cannot do anyway)?

Comment: because that is parsed as `t1 = (t2 = t3)`. The result of `t2 = t3` is a pointer. So `t1 = pointer` isn't valid

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105798/why-must-the-copy-assignment-operator-return-a-reference-const-reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not about the `Point*` argument of `addPoint`, but about the implicit `this` pointer argument:

`operator=` is marked as a `const` function, so inside it, `this` is a pointer-to-`const`. Thus trying to call a non-`const` function on it doesn't work.

You need to mark `operator=` non-`const`.

---

On a related note, you're also returning a *pointer* from `operator=` and taking the right-hand operand by *non*-`const` reference, both of which are weird things to do.

When overloading operators, it's **strongly** recommended to use the canonical signatures, which you can find e.g. [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment).

Comment: yeah, i guess coding c++ while you're a newbie after 5 hours makes me blind. thanks. ill accept answer when its possible..