# Operator overloading C++ f1=f2=7.5

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading

I have a fraction class , I have written functions for almost all the operators like + , - , = , / , * etc.

I have also done it for f1 = 2/3 , f2 = 7.5 where f1 and f2 are fraction objects.

But I dont know how to overload multiple assignment operator i.e.

f1 = f2 = 7.5;

Please help.

Comment: Are you expecting us to guess how your `fraction` class is implemented..?

Comment: No just explain me how to make an overload function which passes this line:  f1=f2=7.5 without any compilation error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105798/why-must-the-copy-assignment-operator-return-a-reference-const-reference

Comment: implement the typical assignment operator. That will work for you

Comment: Return `*this` from the assignment operator (with the return type declared as `MyType&`).

Comment: There is no difference between one assignment operator and multiple.  You just need to overload it in a way such that multiple work (which isn't hard).  Just google how to overload an assignment operator.