# Why do most books recommend that the assignment operator return a reference to *this?

Tags: c++, assignment-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Overloading assignment operator in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447696/overloading-assignment-operator-in-c)
>   [C++ why the assignment operator should return a const ref in order to avoid (a=b)=c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706690/c-why-the-assignment-operator-should-return-a-const-ref-in-order-to-avoid-a-b)

Why do most books recommend that the assignment operator return a refernce to this? Why not a `const` reference?

`const` will make strange code like (a=b)=c not compile which is a good thing.

Comment: ...and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649068/has-anyone-found-the-need-to-declare-the-return-parameter-of-a-copy-assignment-o